# Visual C++ 2010 map/set iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

I'm pulling my hair out with this error.  It's a function to look up addresses in a symbol table for a debugger inside an 8080 emulator.  The idea is this: I have a symbol table with addresses and labels, and the this function takes an address, and tries to find the closest symbol within a given distance (usually 10).  It then returns a string like "label" or "label+2".  It returns NULL if it doesn't find a match close enough.

Everything works as normal, until after the emulated CPU has performed a jump, then Visual C++ asserts "map/set iterators incompatible" on the line with the for loop.  I've seen things on threading problems with regards to this, and it is a multi-threaded application, but the symbol map is only used inside one thread, and is not touched other than to read, once it's been filled at startup.

I've tried while loops, for loops, for each loops, all with or without auto iterators.  I tried the taking out the return inside the loop, making a break with setting symbol and distance to return exact matches at the bottom outside the loop.  It still chokes at the same point.  (Address of 1418, but the function has been called six times prior both returning exact matches or NULL).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map <int, string> symbol_list;

/* -- function that fills the table -- */

const char * look_up_symbol(int address, int max_distance){

  static char buffer[32];
  auto symbol = symbol_list.end();
  int distance; // distance to the current found symbol
  int c_distance; // current distance

  distance = 65536; // more than memory, bigger than big

  for (auto p = symbol_list.begin(); p != symbol_list.end(); ++p){
    if (address == p->first){
      // found an exact match
      strcpy(buffer, p->second.c_str());
      return buffer;
    }
    c_distance = abs(address - p->first);
    if (c_distance <= max_distance){
      // we've found one close enough to consider
      if (c_distance < distance){
        // closer then the closest one considered yet.
        symbol = p;
        distance = c_distance;
      }
    }
  }

  if (symbol  == symbol_list.end()){
    // we didn't find one close enough
    return NULL;
  }

  sprintf(buffer, "%s%+d", symbol->second.c_str(), distance);
  return buffer;

  return NULL;

}
```

This one really has me stumped...I'm not sure how the p can not match symbol_list.end(), since it's an auto type, and there's no code to actually change the content of symbol_list once it's been filled.

Comment: `strcpy` and raw C-style strings should make you nervous.  Use `std::string`!

Comment: Two notes. 1) If two threads call `look_up_symbol` roughly simultaneously, they are gonna have a bad time: there's only one copy of `buffer`, and they are both going to write to it. 2) At 32 characters, `buffer` is rather small. Are you sure you are not overrunning it (writing a string to it that's longer than 31 character plus terminating NUL)? You don't have any checks in place to prevent that.

Comment: On a somewhat related note: `symbol_list.lower_bound(address)` will give you an iterator to the map element with `first >= address`. You only need to look at that element and the previous one (which would have `first < address`) and choose the one that's closer - you don't need to look at every single element. You do have to carefully handle the edge cases, where `lower_bound()` returns `begin()` or `end()`.

Comment: I have not analyzed your code, but you might want to read about the checked iterators (`_SECURE_SCL`). In VS2010, it is disabled in release (for speed), but in prior versions it was always enabled. The whole solution, however, needs to have the same define, for all projects. If a single one is different, you may end up with undefined behavior!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it **was** from the dangers of using raw strings.  I'm usually very good about keeping them under control, but one call up the stack (in the disasssembler function), the c-string that accepts the disassembled instruction was too small.  As originally created, it only needed to hold 9 bytes plus the null at most ("SHLD 1F00" as an example), and when it ran into a longer instruction, it caused problems.  Inside this function, 32 bytes is fine, since function that reads them from files only grabs 23 bytes, which is more than the 21 bytes allowed on the screen to display.

I would and do use std::string, but for some things, C-style strings are much more comfortable for me.  And again, I do my best to treat them with the utmost respect.  But this particular project has short periods of development with long stretches of dust gathering, which is not good when mixed with dangerous coding practices.  Live an' learn.